# Clear all elements of collection contained in other collection

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clear all elements of a collection contained inside another collection.
The code runs ok but the collection is not emptied, and when i try to repopulate it, it just adds new items after the ones already present.

Here is the code i tried :

```
Sub vider_collection(collection_pleine As Collection)
    
    For Each coll In collection_pleine
        Do While coll.Count > 0
            Debug.Print (coll.Count)
            coll.Remove 1
        Loop
    Next
End Sub
```

And here are the collection definition :

```
Sub ajout_collections_1st_plaques()
    
    With Plq_clmn_global
        .Add Plq_clmn1
        .Add Plq_clmn2
        .Add Plq_clmn3
        .Add Plq_clmn4
    End With
    
    With Plq_row_global
        .Add Plq_row1
        .Add Plq_row2
        .Add Plq_row3
        .Add Plq_row4
    End With

End Sub
```

Plq_clmn_global is a collection
Plq_clmn1 is a collection containing Integers

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to your code and declare all variables.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, i tried but it does not work, all the varables used in here are declared (coll included).    I found a workaround by recalling ajout_collections_1st_plaques() before clearing the collections but it makes the code way too slow and i don't think it's the most efficient way to do it

Comment: You can reuse the variable, set it to a new collection `Set collection_pleine = New collection`